# Pip install portfolioopt fatal error C1083

Tags: python, pip, anaconda

I'm trying to install portfolioopt (Win 8.1*64) lib using pip and get those errors:

```
     C:\Users\Alexey\AppData\Local\Programs\Common\Microsoft\Visual C++ for Pytho
n\9.0\VC\Bin\amd64\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /MD /W3 /GS- /DNDEBUG -IC:\Anaconda\inc
lude -IC:\Anaconda\PC /Tcsrc/C/base.c /Fobuild\temp.win-amd64-2.7\Release\src/C/
base.obj
    base.c
    c:\users\alexey\appdata\local\temp\pip-build-30y6av\cvxopt\src\c\cvxopt.h(31
) : fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'complex.h': No such file or di
rectory
    error: command 'C:\\Users\\Alexey\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Common\\Microso
ft\\Visual C++ for Python\\9.0\\VC\\Bin\\amd64\\cl.exe' failed with exit status
2
```

I already have Visual C++ 2008 and Compiler package for python 2.7. How to fix it?

Answer (score 1):

It appears that your problem is with the requirements for portfolioopt, for some reason it doesn't seem to be properly installing the cvxopt package. What I did to fix this problem (I tried and had a similar problem to you) is to separately install the cvxopt package, which I did with this command:

```
    conda install -c https://conda.binstar.org/eswears cvxopt
```

after this package installed I used the pip install command for the portfolioopt package:

```
    pip install portfolioopt
```

and the installation worked.